# How can i upload a very large file to AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am running the command in Powershell

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName "TestBucket" 
               -Key "destdFileNameInBucket.tar" 
               -File "localFile.tar"
               -ServerSideEncryption AES256
```

The issue is that the process just stops with no error; the file localFile.tar is approx 380G.
I thought each bucket can hold 5TB of data ?
How can I write this to the bucket ?

Comment: You can do multi part uploads, like described here: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-upload-large-files/

Comment: and this can be done via Powershell ? Is there an example of this ?

Comment: also whats the pricing with this , for such large files would it be costly ? Is there a pricing tier  can refer to ?

Comment: S3 pricing can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/de/s3/pricing/

Comment: Also quite handy, the AWS cost calculator: https://calculator.aws/#/

Comment: And for the Powershell part: I actually don't know if this is supported in the Powershell version of the CLI - I use the WSL when on Windows.

Comment: never heard of WSL but will have a look , any documentation ?

Comment: WSL is the Linux Subsystem on Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/wsl/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using AWS CLI, which allows use of the `s3 cp` command and supports multipart uploads designed for large files.

Your command should look something like

```
aws s3 cp localFile.tar s3://TestBucket/ -ServerSideEncryption AES256 -Key "destdFileNameInBucket.tar"
```

---

Taken from https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/

Comment: This is assuming the user has logged in via the cli , right ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to set up the CLI beforehand - depends a bit on your account, whether you are using SSO or access keys. Guide for the setup: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html